# Why does assigning a value to a cell change the value to american date format?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'd like an explanation as to *why* the following occurs (I've found a few questions offering partial workarounds, but none explaining what's going on).
So far as I can determine all regional settings are UK:

Format cell A1 as text and enter:
    03/01/2014 16:00

When I run the Sub

```
Sub TestSub()
MsgBox Format(Range("A1").Value, "DD MMM YYYY")
Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Value
MsgBox Format(Range("A2").Value, "DD MMM YYYY")
End Sub
```

I get **03 Jan 2014** and then **01 Mar 2014** - VBA obviously 'knows' that the value is the 3rd of January at the point where I take it out of the cell, what's happening when it goes back in?

Bonus points: can I get it to stop or, failing that, assign the value as a date to another cell without ending up in March?

Answer (score 0):

Does this keep you out of March??

```
Sub TestSub()
    MsgBox Format(Range("A1").Value, "DD MMM YYYY")
    Range("A1").Copy Range("A2")
    MsgBox Format(Range("A2").Value, "DD MMM YYYY")
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, yes - it copies the cell across.  I want to know why assigning the value between cells (and converting from Text to a Date on the way) traverses the Atlantic!